# Show directory tree instead of index.html

Tags: apache, virtualhost, directoryindex, directory-traversal

how can I define apache virtual host to show a directory tree even if index.html/php exists?

Comment: Whats your Apache version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to enabled the `Indexes` option and remove the `DirectoryIndex` option.

If you have `AllowOverride` enabled you can add the following to your .htaccess file.

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex disabled
```

If you get a welcome page, you may need to remove/edit `/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf`.  ON Red Hat derived OS's and others this can interfere with some directory listing.

Comment: Any way to see the directory tree as 'visitor' if index would normally be sent? Given, Options Indexes isn't disabled, of course. Or will visitors of my website really only have the option of guessing in that case?